# DLL like mechanism in OSX

Tags: macos, dynamic-data, automatic-updates

I want to create an app and to be able to update it from the internet.

In my Windows version the actual content is a DLL that I change on each update.

How can I achieve this in OSX? my application is a plug-in and after the initial installation
I cannot override the wrapper file (like the one that loads the DLL in the WIN version)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS X equivalent to a DLL is a Dynamic Library (or dylib).  Here's some info on dylibs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/000-Introduction/Introduction.html

You cannot include resources in a dylib.  If you need to include resources, consider creating a Bundle:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html